# Can I use pivot_longer() with a survey design object from srvyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Is there a way to use `pivot_longer()` with a survey design object produced in `srvyr`? I'd liked to make a facetted graph showing a series of variables, so to do that I want to get four or five demographic variables into a long dataframe and plot the weighted data.

The following code is reproducible, but does install a package. sorry about that, it's the best I could figure out to reproduce my problem. Getting what I need is easy with unweighted data, but I don't know how to do it with weighted data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(srvyr)
#output of dput 
ces2019_web<-tibble::tribble(
  ~cps19_province, ~cps19_education, ~cps19_weight_general_all,
  "24",             "10",         0.681336402893066,
  "24",             "10",         0.681336402893066,
  "22",              "8",         0.650459408760071,
  "22",              "8",          0.88725334405899,
  "22",              "5",          1.65380775928497,
  "22",              "8",         0.650459408760071
)
# convert values to factor type
ces2019_web <- to_factor(ces2019_web)
#Make the survey design 
ces2019_web %>% 
  filter(!is.na(cps19_weight_general_all)) %>% 
  as_survey_design(., weight=cps19_weight_general_all)->des
#Look for two demographic variables similar to what I'm working with 
#Show the ideal end product but for unweighted data
ces2019_web %>% 
  as_factor() %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols=c(1:2)) %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarize(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% 
  knitr::kable()
#Show with weighted data;
#Require a solution
des %>% 
  select(cps19_province, cps19_education) %>% 
  pivot_longer()
```

Comment: There are a few code blocks here that appear to be unnecessary: if they don't change existing data and are merely for your interactive use (and not relevant to the question), then please remove them (it simplifies the problem a bit). If others (like me) do not have `cesR` or `labelled` installed, it might also be helpful if you add the output from `dput(head(ces2019_web))`, with just enough rows to show the variability of the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no plans to implement `pivot_longer` or `pivot_wider` (or other tidyr functions that change the dimensionality of a dataset) in srvyr because they change the dataset in ways that require altering the survey design that can't be automatically determined. You'll need to know how to specify the correct design with the new dataset.

I've always felt that you should pivot (and otherwise tidy) the dataset before converting it to a `tbl_svy`.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. You know much better than me, but it means lots of recreating survey designs depending on the visualization that is desired.